# Add .po and .mo format to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, upload, po, poedit, mo

I needed to add some formats such as **ico** and **svg** in a part of the WordPress theme that I designed, which I did by placing the following code in the `functions.php` file:

```
function upload( $mime_types ) {
  $mime_types[ 'svg' ] = 'image/svg+xml';
  $mime_types[ 'ico' ] = 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon';
  return $mime_types;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'upload', 1, 1 );
```

Now I want to introduce two formats `.po and .mo` to WordPress for support.

My only problem is that I don't know what these two formats are and no matter what I searched for, I didn't find anything.

Does anyone know the type of these two formats?
Or can I use `application/msword (.doc)` for them?

---

**Edit:**

I found the following tutorial for the `.po and .mo` format, but I still couldn't find the format type:

[Opening PO Files](https://filext.com/file-extension/PO)

[Media type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by Dyn to the question [How to make a header for gettext .po files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066051) has your answer for the `.po` file:

> just download an example .po file and have a look inside with a regular text editor. The header contains the following information :
> "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"

The mime type for `.po` is: text/plain.

As for the `.mo` file, this is a binary file. [RFC 2046 (MIME) Part Two: Media Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt) says:

> The "application" media type is to be used for discrete data which do not fit in any of the other categories, and particularly for data to be processed by some type of application program.
> The "octet-stream" subtype is used to indicate that a body contains arbitrary binary data.

The mime type that can be used for `.mo` is: application/octet-stream.

## UPDATE

It looks like there are at least two approaches you can try:

1. wp_check_filetype_and_ext, and
2. ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS in `wp-config.php`

I've tested both. They both work on WordPress version 6.4.

## wp_check_filetype_and_ext

Nathan Johnson's answer from this question: [Allow CSV files to be uploaded](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258192) uses the WordPress filter hook [wp_check_filetype_and_ext](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_check_filetype_and_ext/). The WordPress Docs for this hook say that it:

> Filters the "real" file type of the given file.

`wp_check_filetype_and_ext` in addition to either the [mime_types](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/mime_types/) filter hook or the [upload_mimes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_mimes/) filter hook allow users with at least the Author role to upload `.po` and `.mo` files. You can follow Nathan Johnson's answer more closely to restrict this upload privilege to specific user roles. See code sample below.

### Code sample

```
function add_my_mimes( $mime_types ) {
    $mime_types['mo'] = "application/octet-stream";
    $mime_types['po'] = "text/plain";

    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'add_my_mimes' );


// Add filter to check filetype and extension
function wpse_check_filetype_and_ext( $args, $file, $filename, $mimes ) {
    $extension = pathinfo( $filename )[ 'extension' ];
    if ( 'mo' === $extension ) {
        $args = array(
            'ext'             => 'mo',
            'type'            => 'application/octet-stream',
            'proper_filename' => $filename,
        );
    } elseif ( 'po' === $extension ) {
        $args = array(
            'ext'             => 'po',
            'type'            => 'text/plain',
            'proper_filename' => $filename,
        );
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'wpse_check_filetype_and_ext', 10, 4 );
```

## ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS

The `wp-config.php` update suggested under the heading **Non-Image File Upload Error** in this WP Engine post [MIME Types in WordPress](https://wpengine.com/support/mime-types-wordpress/#Non-Image_File_Upload_Error) says:

> Add the following line to the wp-config.php file. This will allow non-image uploads for administrators only:

```
define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true );
```

Comment: Hello. I have tried both models before and WordPress does not allow uploading. That's why I said I couldn't find the desired type. These two files (.po and .mo) do not have a specific type? Does WordPress support these files?

Comment: I think that even if the files are typed correctly, WordPress still does not allow you to upload these files. Maybe this is one of the limitations of WordPress. Because I checked these types of questions, I realized that none of them failed to upload such files in WordPress.

Comment: Although my problem was not solved, I accept your answer, because no matter what I searched for, I got the same answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Benjamin Hi. I updated my answer with two possible solutions.

Comment: **Thank you**. My problem is completely solved. I easily uploaded the files **(.po and .mo)** to **WordPress**. Again, thank you very much for the great advice and code you have written for me.